# Can I use PyWinAuto to automate WPF desktop application?

Tags: python, wpf, controls, ui-automation, pywinauto

I am working on automating my desktop application.

It is completely designed using WPF controls.

Can you please tell me if I can use PyWinAuto to automate this application ?

I would like to know how to fetch the unique control ids of these wpf objects to be able to control them using automation.
Is there a spy tool to fetch these id's ?
I already tried SWAPY 64 bit. But it displays control id as '0' and the highlight is on the main application window and I am unable to highlight the smaller wpf controls available inside that window.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pywinauto 0.6.0+ is automatically tested specifically on WPF application. So it can automate WPF controls, but SWAPY doesn't support this new feature unfortunately. So you need to learn pywinauto in more details. [Getting Started Guide](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html) will help you to find `Inspect.exe` (modern spy tool) which is included into Windows SDK. It also explains a lot about pywinauto fundamentals: backends, window specifications, attribute resolution magic and more.